# Serializable Struct with Bytes Array

Tags: rust

How would I serialize a struct like:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct MyStruct {
    values: [u8; 64],
}
```

The error I get states:

```
^^^ the trait `serde::Deserialize<'_>` is not implemented for `[u8; 64]`
```

But I'm not sure I understand why this is an issue since it has a known length.

Comment: unfortunately this is a limitation of generic.

Comment: Unfortunately Serde defines Serialize/Deserialize impls for arrays up to size 32, but we have [workaround](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/631#issuecomment-322677033). Also it is published as a [crate](https://github.com/est31/serde-big-array)